# Can't access the 'Site Settings' page after enabling Forms Based Authentication

Tags: sharepoint-designer, forms-authentication, site-settings

I've setup Forms Based Authentication on my Sharepoint site using various online tutorials. It has both FBA and Windows Authentication and everything works as expected apart from the 'Site Settings' page. When I click to it, it shows me a nice error:

```
Error

An unexpected error has occurred.

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Correlation ID: 91c66ecd-d415-4559-ac26-63c05b1cb3de

Date and Time: 5/9/2012 11:16:00 AM
```

Originally the site was just Windows auth, but I add FBA to it.

When I say Site settings page, I mean just the page that is linked to from the menu (/_layouts/settings.aspx). I can still get to pages that this page provides links to. So for example, I can still get to the 'Title, Description, and Icon' settings page by typing in the url directly (/_layouts/prjsetng.aspx).

Originally, I didn't notice this, but noticed that I could no longer open the site in SharePoint Designer. Because of this I read that I could extend the site, which is just set as windows authentication, and that did indeed allow me to open the site in designer.

This also allows me to open the Site settings page using the new url, so to clarify:
http://admin-pc:16132/_layouts/settings.aspx (Original site, FBA and Windows, settings page doesn't work)
http://admin-pc:48028/_layouts/settings.aspx (extended site, windows only)

My FBA login I use is just a standard user, so it doesn't have access to the site settings page, I use the windows login to do all site administration stuff.

Essentially, I'd like to know whats going on, and if it's actually possible to do everything on one URL.

Hope someone can help,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check the ULS logs to see the details of the error with that correlation ID? If so, could you please post that information?

Comment: Brilliant, still new to SharePoint and didn't know how to view these. Got a viewer now, turns out the FBA pack I used was adding multiple controls with the same ID onto the page,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Claims would allow you to authenticated with either Forms and Windows, true! But without giving proper permissions to the FBA User on the Site Collection do not expect it to receive Administrative permissions.

Enabling Claims authentication on your Web Application would not even be necessary to Extend the Web Application, it will show the dialog box enabling selection of the preferred Authentication Method.

Probably you need to revise your configuration of the FBA. I've found these very useful:

1. http://saiabhilash.blogspot.com/2012/03/claims-based-authentication-in.html (with SQL )
2. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/9883.how-to-configure-ad-lds-claims-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2010-step-by-step.aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to reply. Actually, I think my FBA is setup alright, however I was having that issue where my users weren't coming up in people searches as in the first link so thanks for that, have something to guide me now!

Comment: I use the FBA pack from Codeplex (http://sharepoint2010fba.codeplex.com). After I deployed it the site settings page stopped being accessible, however when I undeployed it, the page was once again accessible, so I can't think what it could be because as far as I can tell, it simply adds a few links to this page.The pages that all the links on the site settings page actually still work when you manually type in the url.

(Sorry for the double reply, pressed enter too soon)

Comment: I would strongly suggest you configure FBA step by step yourself using these guides, this for sure will give some insight on what is going on so you could troubleshoot yourself later on.

Comment: Thanks for your input on this, turns out the FBA pack I used was adding multiple controls with the same ID onto the page and was causing the site settings page to error!